# during dynamic linking/loading, how is the base address obtained

Tags: c, elf, dynamic-loading

i am writing my own dynamic linker/loader

my PRIMARY concern is getting the BASE ADDRESS correct and valid, as at the moment it is 0 (nil)

in which i have not worked on in 11 months and will probably need to re-learn most of my linker/loader aswell as ELF spec

which aims to provide the following capabilities:

1. able to load and execute any libc compiled application including glibc, musl, uclibc, klibc, and others, and thus MUST be independent of such libs,

for example if it can compile with glibc but cannot be compiled with musl than it is broken and is thus dependent on glibc to compile, which if being compiled on a musl based distribution, is obviously not an option

2. to be able to redirect shared object loading to $APP_LOCATION/../

provided $APP_LOCATION is for example, app/bin/app, it redirects /lib/blah to app/bin/../lib/blah and if the path does not exists fallsback to /lib/blah

this is something which CANNOT be achieved in the gnu dynamic linker, and cannnot be pre-loaded in ld.so.

3. to be able to dlopen any valid symbol from any shared object, including local and nested symbols if known, aswell as C++ symbols (decoded/encoded via libiberty) , something which also cannot be done via hooking dlsym due to how dlsym itself works (eg it is only limited to global link symbols)

an example of this is:

(due to posting the files would result in exceeding 30,000 characters)

test_loader.c : 
https://github.com/mgood7123/universal-dynamic-loader/blob/master/loader/test_loader.c

```
additional_flags="-w"
debug="-g3 -O0 $additional_flags"
share="$debug -fPIC -shared"
```

void* test = dlopen("./files/test_lib.so") : gcc $share test_lib.c test_lib2.c -o files/test_lib.so : https://github.com/mgood7123/universal-dynamic-loader/blob/master/loader/test_lib.c and https://github.com/mgood7123/universal-dynamic-loader/blob/master/loader/test_lib2.c

void* testCPlusPlus = dlopen("./files/test++_lib.so") : g++ $share test++_lib.cpp test++_lib2.cpp -o files/test++_lib.so : https://github.com/mgood7123/universal-dynamic-loader/blob/master/loader/test%2B%2B_lib.cpp and https://github.com/mgood7123/universal-dynamic-loader/blob/master/loader/test%2B%2B_lib2.cpp

so far this *works* for almost all libraries (as in all libraries compiled as shared objects, not all libc variants such as musl or klib) except glibc which requires initialization of variables such as stdin/stdout/stderr and others, tho strlen, write(), work fine, have not tested strcmp and others, BUT printf and puts hang upon being executed

musl does not seem to have this problem and all of its functions seem to work find though i have not tested it extensively, strlen, write, puts, and printf work in musl with no problems

(idk which term it is called officially since the ELF spec seems to refer to it as dynamic loader, while gnu refers to it as dynamic linker)

and during dynamic linking, how is the base address obtained in order to initialize shared object files

granted i CANNOT post the full code of my linker as it is
257,903 characters, and the post limit is
30,000 characters

this base address is required for R_x86_64_RELATIVE relocations, which i believe contain the DT_INIT and DT_INIT_ARRAY functions/function arrays pointers among others

when i attempt to figure it out i get... well i get two things

1. my relocation segfaults when attempting to assign to the computed base address + offset:

   ```
   R_X86_64_RELATIVE            calculation: B + A (base address + r_addend)
   library[library_index].base_address    =          (nil)
   reloc->r_offset =          (nil)+0x000000200e78=0x000000200e78
   reloc->r_addend =          (nil)+0x000000000590=0x000000000590
   ((char**)((char*)library[library_index].base_address + reloc->r_offset)) = 0x200e78
   Segmentation fault
   ```

which brings up problem number 2

2. the base address is incorrect

   ```
   searching indexes for "./DT_INIT.so" incase it has already been loaded
   current index 0 holds "./DT_INIT.so"
   index 0 holds desired library "./DT_INIT.so"
   map succeded with address: 0x7f132f66a000
   calling round_up
   returning = 0x7f1320000000
   memmove: round_up(0x7f131dbe0010, 0x000010000000)+0x000000200000 = 0x7f1320200000
   calling round_up
   returning = 0x7f1320000000
   dest = 0x7f1320200000
   dest = 0x7f1320000000
   library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index].p_vaddr = 0x000000200e78
   library[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_paddr = 0x000000200e78
   library[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_vaddr = 0x000000200e78
   calling round_down
   returning = 0x000000200000
   calling round_down
   returning = 0x000000200000
   calling round_nearest
   returning = 0x000000201000
   base address range = 0x7f1320000000 - 0x7f1320201028
   mapping = 0x7f1320000000
   base address =          (nil)
   ```

which is done via

```
dlopen(lib) > dlopen_(lib) > init_(lib) > {
                                            > init(lib) // mmaps the lib
                                            > map()
**base address is assigned in the function map(), which aswell
as assigning the base address, also maps the PT_LOADS**
}

int init(char * lib) {
    if (library[library_index].struct_init != "initialized") init_struct();
    if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "current index %d holds \"%s\"\nsearching indexes for \"%s\" incase it has already been loaded\n", library_index, library[library_index].last_lib, lib);

    library_index = search(lib);
    library[library_index].last_lib = lib;
    library[library_index].current_lib = lib;
    if (library[library_index].array == NULL) {
        int fd = open(lib, O_RDONLY);
        if (fd < 0) {
            if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "cannot open \"%s\", returned %i\n", lib, fd);
            return -1;
        }
        library[library_index].len = 0;
        library[library_index].len = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
        lseek(fd, 0, 0);
        library[library_index].array = mmap (NULL, library[library_index].len, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, fd, 0);
        if (library[library_index].array == MAP_FAILED) {
            if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "map failed\n");
            exit;
        } else {
            if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "map succeded with address: %014p\n", library[library_index].array);
            return 0;
        }
    } else return 0;
    return -1;
}

int prot_from_phdr(const int p_flags)
{
    int prot = 0;
    if (p_flags & PF_R)
    {
        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "PROT_READ|");
        prot |= PROT_READ;
    }
    if (p_flags & PF_W)
    {
        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "PROT_WRITE|");
        prot |= PROT_WRITE;
    }
    if (p_flags & PF_X)
    {
        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "PROT_EXEC|");
        prot |= PROT_EXEC;
    }
    return prot;
}

uintptr_t round_nearest(uintptr_t value, uintptr_t size)
{
    printf("calling %s\n", __func__);
    uintptr_t result = 0;
    uintptr_t remainder = value % size;
    if (remainder < size/2) { result = value - remainder; } else { result = value + size - remainder; }
    printf("returning = %014p\n", result);
    return result;
}


uintptr_t round_down(uintptr_t value, uintptr_t size)
{
    printf("calling %s\n", __func__);
    uintptr_t result = 0;
    result = (value/size)*size;
    printf("returning = %014p\n", result);
    return result;
}

uintptr_t round_up(uintptr_t value, uintptr_t size)
{
    printf("calling %s\n", __func__);
    uintptr_t result = 0;
    result = value ? size * ((value + (size - 1)) / size) : size;
    printf("returning = %014p\n", result);
    return result;
}

// special version specifically for PT_LOAD handling
int read_fast_verifyb(const char *src, int len_of_source, char **dest, int requested_len, Elf64_Phdr PT_LOAD_F, Elf64_Phdr PT_LOAD_L) {
    void * align = 0x10000000;
    *dest = malloc(requested_len+align+PT_LOAD_L.p_align);
    if (len_of_source < requested_len) memcpy(*dest, src, len_of_source);
    else memcpy(*dest, src, requested_len);
    if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "memmove: round_up(%014p, %014p)+%014p = %014p\n", *dest, align, PT_LOAD_L.p_align, round_up(*dest, align)+PT_LOAD_L.p_align);
    *dest = memmove(round_up(*dest, align)+PT_LOAD_L.p_align, *dest, requested_len);
    if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "dest = %014p\n", *dest);
    *dest = memmove(*dest-PT_LOAD_L.p_align, *dest, PT_LOAD_F.p_memsz);
    if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "dest = %014p\n", *dest);
    return requested_len;
}

void map() {
    if (library[library_index].is_mapped == 0) {
        library[library_index]._elf_header = (Elf64_Ehdr *) library[library_index].array;
        library[library_index]._elf_program_header = (Elf64_Phdr *)((unsigned long)library[library_index]._elf_header + library[library_index]._elf_header->e_phoff);

/*
the very first thing we do is obtain the base address

Base Address
The virtual addresses in the program headers might not represent the actual virtual addresses
of the program's memory image. Executable files typically contain absolute code. To let the
process execute correctly, the segments must reside at the virtual addresses used to build the
executable file. On the other hand, shared object segments typically contain
position-independent code. This lets a segment's virtual address change from one process to
another, without invalidating execution behavior. Though the system chooses virtual addresses
for individual processes, it maintains the segments’ relative positions. Because
position-independent code uses relative addressing between segments, the difference between
virtual addresses in memory must match the difference between virtual addresses in the file.

The difference between the virtual address of any segment in memory and the corresponding
virtual address in the file is thus a single constant value for any one executable or shared object
in a given process. This difference is the base address. One use of the base address is to relocate
the memory image of the program during dynamic linking.

An executable or shared object file's base address is calculated during execution from three
values: the virtual memory load address, the maximum page size, and the lowest virtual address
of a program's loadable segment. To compute the base address, one determines the memory
address associated with the lowest p_vaddr value for a PT_LOAD segment. This address is
truncated to the nearest multiple of the maximum page size. The corresponding p_vaddr value
itself is also truncated to the nearest multiple of the maximum page size. The base address is
the difference between the truncated memory address and the truncated p_vaddr value.
*/

        // aquire the first and last PT_LOAD'S
        int PT_LOADS=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < library[library_index]._elf_header->e_phnum; ++i) {
            switch(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_type)
            {
                case PT_LOAD:
//                         if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "i = %d\n", i);
//                         if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "PT_LOADS = %d\n", PT_LOADS);
                    if (!PT_LOADS)  {
//                             if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "saving first load\n");
                        library[library_index].First_Load_Header_index = i;
                    }
                    if (PT_LOADS) {
//                             if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "saving last load\n");
                        library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index = i;
                    }
                    PT_LOADS=PT_LOADS+1;
                    break;
            }
        }
        size_t span = library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index].p_vaddr + library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index].p_memsz - library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].First_Load_Header_index].p_vaddr;


        read_fast_verifyb(library[library_index].array, library[library_index].len, &library[library_index].mapping_start, span, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].First_Load_Header_index], library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index]);

        fprintf(stderr, "library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index].p_vaddr = %014p\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index].p_vaddr);

        // aquire the lowest PT_LOAD'S
        Elf64_Addr lowest_p_vaddr = 0;
        int lowest_idx = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < library[library_index]._elf_header->e_phnum; ++i) {
            switch(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_type)
            {
                case PT_LOAD:
                    if (!lowest_p_vaddr) {
                        lowest_p_vaddr = library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_vaddr;
                        lowest_idx = i;
                    }
                    if (lowest_p_vaddr < library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_memsz) {
                        lowest_p_vaddr = library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_vaddr;
                        lowest_idx = i;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        size_t pagesize = 0x1000;
        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "library[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_paddr = %014p\nlibrary[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_vaddr = %014p\n",library[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_paddr, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_vaddr);
        Elf64_Addr truncated_physical_address = round_down(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_paddr, pagesize);
        Elf64_Addr truncated_virtual_address = round_down(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[lowest_idx].p_vaddr, pagesize);
        library[library_index].base_address = truncated_physical_address - truncated_virtual_address;
//      library[library_index].base_address = library[library_index].mapping_start;

        library[library_index].align = round_nearest(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[library[library_index].Last_Load_Header_index].p_vaddr, pagesize);
//      library[library_index].base_address = library[library_index].mapping_start - library[library_index].align;
        library[library_index].mapping_end = library[library_index].mapping_start+span;

        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "base address range = %014p - %014p\nmapping = %014p\nbase address = %014p\n", library[library_index].mapping_start, library[library_index].mapping_end, library[library_index].mapping_start, library[library_index].base_address);

//      abort_();
        // base address aquired, map all PT_LOAD segments adjusting by base address then continue with the rest
        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\n\n\nfind %014p, %014p, (int) 1239\n\n\n\n", library[library_index].mapping_start, library[library_index].mapping_end);

        if (library[library_index].mapping_start == 0x00000000) abort_();
        int PT_LOADS_CURRENT = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < library[library_index]._elf_header->e_phnum; ++i) {
            switch(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_type)
            {
                case PT_LOAD:
                    PT_LOADS_CURRENT = PT_LOADS_CURRENT + 1;
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "mapping PT_LOAD number %d\n", PT_LOADS_CURRENT);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\t\tp_flags:  %014p\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_flags);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\t\tp_offset: %014p\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_offset);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\t\tp_vaddr:  %014p\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_vaddr);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\t\tp_paddr:  %014p\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_paddr);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\t\tp_filesz: %014p\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_filesz);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\t\tp_memsz:  %014p\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_memsz);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\t\tp_align:  %014p\n\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_align);

                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "\tp_flags: %014p", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_flags);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, " p_offset: %014p", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_offset);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, " p_vaddr: %014p", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_vaddr);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, " p_paddr: %014p", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_paddr);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, " p_filesz: %014p", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_filesz);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, " p_memsz: %014p", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_memsz);
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, " p_align: %014p\n\n\n", library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_align);

                    if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "mprotect(%014p+round_down(%014p, %014p), %014p, ", library[library_index].mapping_start, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_vaddr, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_align, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_memsz);
                    prot_from_phdr(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_flags);
                    if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, ");\n");
                    errno = 0;
                    int check_mprotect_success = mprotect(library[library_index].mapping_start+round_down(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_vaddr, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_align), round_up(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_memsz, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_align), library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_flags);
                    if (errno == 0)
                    {
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "mprotect on %014p succeded with size: %014p\n", library[library_index].mapping_start+round_down(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_vaddr, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_align), round_up(library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_memsz, library[library_index]._elf_program_header[i].p_align));
                        print_maps();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (bytecmpq(global_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "mprotect failed with: %s (errno: %d, check_mprotect_success = %d)\n", strerror(errno), errno, check_mprotect_success);
                        print_maps();
                        abort_();
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        library[library_index].is_mapped = 1;
    }
}

int
init_(const char * filename) {
    init(filename);
    if (library[library_index].init__ == 1) return 0;
    library[library_index]._elf_header = (Elf64_Ehdr *) library[library_index].array;
    read_section_header_table_(library[library_index].array, library[library_index]._elf_header, &library[library_index]._elf_symbol_table);
    obtain_rela_plt_size(library[library_index].array, library[library_index]._elf_header, library[library_index]._elf_symbol_table);
    if(!strncmp((char*)library[library_index]._elf_header->e_ident, "\177ELF", 4)) {
        map();
        ...
    }
    ...
}

void *
dlopen_(const char * cc)
{
    if (library[library_index].init_lock == 1) {
        if (bytecmpq(ldd_quiet, "no") == 0) fprintf(stderr, "dlopen: LOCKED\n");
        return "-1";
    };
    if ( if_valid(cc) == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\"%s\" not found\n", cc);
        errno = 0;
        return "-1";
    }
    init_(cc);
    ...
}

void *
dlopen(const char * cc) {
    get_needed(cc);
    return dlopen_(cc);
}
```

in which this is the structure of the library[]

```
struct lib
{
    char * rootlib;
    char * rootusrlib;
    int init_lock;
    char * struct_init;
    char * library_name;
    char ** NEEDED;
    int NEEDED_COUNT;
    char library_first_character;
    char * library_len;
    char * library_symbol;
    Elf64_Ehdr * _elf_header;
    Elf64_Phdr * _elf_program_header;
    Elf64_Shdr * _elf_symbol_table;
    char *strtab;
    size_t len;
    char * array;
    char * current_lib;
    char * last_lib;
    int is_mapped;
    size_t align;
    Elf64_Addr mapping_start;
    Elf64_Addr base_address;
    Elf64_Addr mapping_end;
    int init__;
    int PT_DYNAMIC_;
    char * tmp99D;
    Elf64_Dyn * dynamic;
    int First_Load_Header_index;
    int Last_Load_Header_index;
    size_t RELA_PLT_SIZE;
    int _R_X86_64_NONE;
    int _R_X86_64_64;
    int _R_X86_64_PC32;
    int _R_X86_64_GOT32;
    int _R_X86_64_PLT32;
    int _R_X86_64_COPY;
    int _R_X86_64_GLOB_DAT;
    int _R_X86_64_JUMP_SLOT;
    int _R_X86_64_RELATIVE;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTPCREL;
    int _R_X86_64_32;
    int _R_X86_64_32S;
    int _R_X86_64_16;
    int _R_X86_64_PC16;
    int _R_X86_64_8;
    int _R_X86_64_PC8;
    int _R_X86_64_DTPMOD64;
    int _R_X86_64_DTPOFF64;
    int _R_X86_64_TPOFF64;
    int _R_X86_64_TLSGD;
    int _R_X86_64_TLSLD;
    int _R_X86_64_DTPOFF32;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTTPOFF;
    int _R_X86_64_TPOFF32;
    int _R_X86_64_PC64;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTOFF64;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTPC32;
    int _R_X86_64_GOT64;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTPCREL64;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTPC64;
    int _Deprecated1;
    int _R_X86_64_PLTOFF64;
    int _R_X86_64_SIZE32;
    int _R_X86_64_SIZE64;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTPC32_TLSDESC;
    int _R_X86_64_TLSDESC_CALL;
    int _R_X86_64_TLSDESC;
    int _R_X86_64_IRELATIVE;
    int _R_X86_64_RELATIVE64;
    int _Deprecated2;
    int _Deprecated3;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTPLT64;
    int _R_X86_64_GOTPCRELX;
    int _R_X86_64_REX_GOTPCRELX;
    int _R_X86_64_NUM;
    int _R_X86_64_UNKNOWN;
    Elf64_Addr * GOT;
    Elf64_Addr * GOT2;
    Elf64_Addr * PLT;
} library[512];
extern struct lib library[512];
```

as i am not entirely sure what "truncated to the nearest multiple" means buts since p_paddr and p_vaddr are the same any calulation done on each will yeild 0 when "The base address is the difference between the truncated memory address and the truncated p_vaddr value."  unless i im interperating this incorrectly:

```
An executable or shared object file's base address is calculated during execution from three
values: the virtual memory load address, the maximum page size, and the lowest virtual address
of a program's loadable segment. To compute the base address, one determines the memory
address associated with the lowest p_vaddr value for a PT_LOAD segment. This address is
truncated to the nearest multiple of the maximum page size. The corresponding p_vaddr value
itself is also truncated to the nearest multiple of the maximum page size. The base address is
the difference between the truncated memory address and the truncated p_vaddr value.
```

Comment: Are you trying to write your own share library loader? otherwise just use `dlopen`, `dlsym` and `dlclose`

Comment: @doron yes i am, also i cannot use dlopen/dlsym/dlclose as mine is for a specific purpose and aims to provide the following capabilities: 1. to be able to redirect shared object loading to ./ and if the path does not exist fall back to / , something which CANNOT be achieved in the gnu dynamic linker NOT can it be pre-loaded in to it, 2. to be able to dlopen any valid symbol from any shared object, including local and nested symbols if known, something which also cannot be done via hooking dlsym due to how dlsym itself works (eg it is only limited to global link symbols)

Comment: Dynamic linking is dependent on the binary format.  Are we to assume you're interested in ELF?

Comment: @JohnBollinger yes, ELF will be my primary target

Comment: Why is `DT_RPATH` set to e.g. `$ORIGIN` not suitable for finding libraries in your custom directories? And your point 3) is crazy: At runtime you really are only meant to only resolve the public symbols. On some architectures (like PPC) calling directly into a non-public function **will crash**, because special base pointer registers must be set and restored during inter-module calls! If what you need is to change the visibility of symbols (public, hidden, ...), you can do that through use of `__attribute__((visibility("default")))`'s in GCC.

Comment: I've been going over it, but I'm not sure what the actual question is here.  I could see "what do the specs mean when they say 'truncated to the nearest multiple'?", but the question seems to be asking much more than that.

Comment: BTW, `x` truncated to the nearest multiple of `n` means `x - (x % n)`, or an equivalent.  If `n` is a power of two then the computation can be performed by masking off the appropriate number of least-significant bits.

Comment: @JohnBollinger ill try that... and i get  200000  for p_paddr and 200000 for p_vaddr  ;-;   which still gets me 0

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist from what i can gather, DT_RPATH, rpath, and $ORIGIN all seem to be a COMPILE_TIME only feature, and cannot be changed at runtime, ei without using pathelf to explicitly modify the rpath of the application, also it doesnt HURT to be able to access non public symbols, it is up to the devoloper to be responsible and only obtain functions and variables that they KNOW will not crash the application when called or modified, as this is not a normal/general thing to do but you CAN do it anyway, provided you are responsible with it

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist eg its like granting a process root and allowing it to do whatever it wants, as long as it is RESPONSIBLE and does not access/touch/delete stuff it is not supposed to access/touch/delete than it can do what ever it wants and access/touch/delete what ever it wants

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist also, for 3. specifically for C++ symbols portion, being able to open those functions without needing to recompile it with, for example, extern C for every function indented to be dlopened, can be usefull as you dont need to recompile it, and you can just open the functions directly provided you know their exact name if there are duplicate functions with different operators (which there CAN be) (for example, dlsym(testCPlusPlus, "test()::{lambda()#1}::operator()() const");  and  dlsym(testCPlusPlus, "test");  both can be used to obtain the exact same C++ function)

Comment: @IwillnotexistIdonotexist i also intend to make it capable of obtaining a specific symbol from a specific file, for example, if multiple source files have the same symbols as static, it should be able to correctly detect those symbol, the files they belong to, and obtain the correct specified symbol from the specified file, for example: `//     39:      0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test_lib2.c , //     40:      8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 bar_p , //     35:      0 FILE    LOCAL  DEFAULT  ABS test_lib.c , //     36:      8 OBJECT  LOCAL  DEFAULT   23 bar_p` (addresses ommited cus char len)